# suffix in front of SSH public key

Tags: ssh

I generated varios(DSA, RSA, ECDSA, etc) SSH keys with `ssh-keygen` and with latest version of `PuTTY Key Generator` and both utilities suffix the public key with a same string. I mean, for example, both suffix RSA key with `ssh-rsa`, ED25519 key with `ssh-ed25519` or RSA-1 key with a key length(for example `2048`). Does this suffix format come from some standard? Are those same suffixes used by all utilities which generate an SSH key-pairs?

Answer (score 2):

Nit: these names come *before* the blob and thus are **prefixes** not suffixes.

This standard for the publickey *file* format is **set by OpenSSH**, which also also uses it in the `known_hosts` and `authorized_keys` files with some more (also prefix!) fields added. See `man sshd` on Unix with OpenSSH installed [or the latest version on the web](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd) under "AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT" and "SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS FILE FORMAT". All **version 2 keys use a string for keytype and a base64-encoded blob** of the publickey as transmitted during SSH(v2) key-exchange, which is defined by several RFCs.

The online manpage no longer includes version 1 keys, although AFAICT all releases to date (through 7.3) still support version 1 BUT strongly discourage its use because it is long obsolete and broken. **Version 1 used three decimal numbers: nbits, exponent (small), and modulus (large).**

PuTTYgen proactively displays the OpenSSH format, but the SavePublicKey button (or File menu item) writes the **different though related format defined by [rfc4716](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4716)** which is also used by OpenSSH `ssh-keygen -e/-i`. I understand the 'commercial' SSH implementation (fka Tectia) uses this format can't confirm personally.

Keytypes for 'plain' keys are generally defined by the SSHv2 RFCs, linked by [an IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ssh-parameters/ssh-parameters.xhtml#ssh-parameters-19). OpenSSH also supports its own form of certificates using keytypes in the vendor-defined format `something@openssh.com` which aren't registered. Finally, OpenSSH uses the standard-form name `ssh-ed25519` even though AFAICT [this is still in draft and not yet an RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-curdle-ssh-ed25519-00).